# Regex redirect for /year/month/post to /post

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect

I've decided to bite the bullet and redirect my old WordPress post links which were in the /year/month/post format (eg, /2018/06/my-post) to just /post.

The [Yoast tool](https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php) for generating the regex rule suggests this:

```
rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)” https://donaldjenkins.com/$3 permanent;
```

The rule works for posts, but the problem is that it also now redirects all my monthly archives, which are in the /year/month/ format (without anything appended, obviously) to the root.

I haven't been ablate find a way to redirect the posts, but not the archives, despite the fact that there is a difference between the two, namely that the monthly archives have nothing after /year/month (eg, https://donaldjenkins.com/2018/06).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> namely that the monthly archives have nothing after /year/month (eg, https://donaldjenkins.com/2018/06).

make your pattern match at least one character for the third part instead of zero as well:

```
rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.+)" https://donaldjenkins.com/$3 permanent;
```

(assuming `https://donaldjenkins.com/2018/06/` is a valid archive as well)